# How I can debug scope variables from the browser console?

Tags: angularjs, debugging, variables, angularjs-scope

*Note: I am replacing this question to improve rating.*

How I can debug angular scope variable from the console? Usually, I can do the same using `{{angular_scope_variable_or_expression}}` within HTML. Sometimes, I need to quickly find the value of a scope variable while I am debugging with the console and developer tools of Chrome Browser. I was able to use the following expression from the console:

`angular.element($('#element_id')).controller('ngModel').$viewValue`

to debug the model value of a given element using element ID. But if I have defined a scope variable, how I can check its value from the console?

Tarek

## Old Question:

*Note: this is the old question. Please ignore.*

I implemented a simple example using angular-signature control based on this library:

https://github.com/legalthings/angular-signature

When working with the simple example, I get this error as soon as the page is loaded:

```
VM697 angular.min.js:103 Error: [$compile:nonassign] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.8/$compile/nonassign?p0=undefined&p1=signaturePad
    at Error (native)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js:6:416
    at l (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js:58:364)
    at f (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js:58:441)
    at Object.<anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js:109:503)
    at l.$digest (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js:123:310)
    at l.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js:126:362)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js:17:448
    at Object.e [as invoke] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js:37:96)
    at d (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js:17:369)
```

and when I draw the signature, I see this error in the console:

```
VM697 angular.min.js:103 TypeError: f is not a function
```

However, the signature is working, and the Data URL is being retrieved.

Check sample here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/TvpmtxjulMFHtTCR6SnZ?p=preview

Press F12 to see the console errors.

Is there something wrong with my code?

Tarek

Comment: Nope, seems to be localized to just the online environments. I replicated your sample on my machine and it does not drop that error when used.

Comment: Thanks! Do you see the errors when you run it from the plnkr link I provided?

Comment: The compile error happens locally for me even with angular 1.5.8. I do not get the VM697 error with angular 1.5.8. The compile error seems to be caused by an 'undefined' value being assigned to a property of the directive: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/nonassign?p0=undefined&p1=dataurl&p2=signaturePad

Comment: So what is the bottom line? I think I will go with ng-signature-pad control instead. I don't see errors with ng-signature-pad, and seems to work better in the sample I developed.

Comment: Yup I got the same error as you, but I think it's related to Plnkr and not your code.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. I am still in the beginning. I have to chose a reliable plugin for my work. If anyone would recommend angular-signature over ng-signature-pad or vise versa, please let me know. For now, I started my work with ng-signature-pad.

Comment: Just to let you know that I have changed the question.